# 18.04.02 installer crash

Tags: live-usb

Ive been trying to install the desktop version ubuntu 18.04.02 on a pc for the last few days but every time the installer fails at the point where it starts copying files to the target hdd. I get an error message saying 'the file on the target drive does not match the installer, this is often due to a faulty hdd or dirty cd'. The pc is a gigabyte motherboard HD3 85 and intel i7, with 16 Gb ram.The hdd is a brand new WD Blue 1TB.

There is nothing obvious in the bios settings that would cause the upset. I have also tried the install with a new 1TB Seagate but no success. Ive tried using different startup thumbdrives both usb 2 and 3, and dvd but always the installation fails. Im at a loss why it keeps failing. Is there a bug with the installer?

Comment: Have you validated the ISO after download, or more importantly validated the install media (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu)  ie. ensure you had a perfect download & perfect write to thumb-drive or cd

Comment: The installer works flawlessly on all my test hardware, so I doubt that an installer bug is the cause of your problem.

Comment: Ive verified the checksum is ok. The install media no, but have tried several thumbs which Ive used previously to create startup disks for 14.04 and 16.04 and 18.04 for other pcs, and they all worked successfully. I just tried installing 19.04 and encountered the same problem. Im starting to suspect it may be a hardware issue but ruled this out initially as this pc is like brand new, the motherboard is new, the psu is new, the case is clean. new hdd, new cpu cooler, new system and case fans

Comment: Checked the connectors on the motherboard, disconnected all drives except the boot drive and dvd writer. 18.04 and 19.04 installer still crashing. After several more futile attempts with ubuntu I installed Linux Mint 19 successfully and its been running smoothly since the install. So whatever the problem with the ubuntu installation it cant be hardware related